# The approximation of the unique solution by the FEM

Tags: numerical-methods, soft-question, finite-element-method

Let consider the weak formulation of an elliptic PDE $a(u,v) = l(v)$, where $a$ is coercive and bounded and $l$ is a bounded functional on the Hilbert space $V=H^1(\Omega)$ (or $H^1_0(\Omega)$). Then, Lax Milgram will tell us there exists a UNIQUE solution $u \in V$ of the above problem for all $v \in V$. After that, we consider $V_h$ a finite dimensional subspace
of V (in practice, we will use piecewise polynomials to construct this subspace) and we change our weak formulation to find $u_h \in V_h$ such that $a(u_h,v_h) = l(v_h)$ for all $v_h \in V_h$.

My question is that we know that the solution is UNIQUE and it's contained in the $V$ space, and we know that $V_h \subset V$, So what if $u \in V-V_h$, what is the benefit to try finding $u_h$ ? and if $u \in V_h$, is it $u_h = u$ ??

Comment: What is $V-V_h$? Is it $V\setminus V_h$?

Comment: yes, the complement of $V_h$ in $V$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to find a *good approximation* to $u$. Céa's lemma tells you that
$$
\|u-u_h\|\leq c\inf_{v\in V_h}\|u-v\|,\qquad\qquad(*)
$$
that is, the error of $u_h$ is, up to a constant factor, as good as the error of the best approximation from $V_h$. So if $V_h$ has good approximation properties, then $u-u_h$ will be very small.

This also answers your second question, because if $u\in V_h$, then the right hand side of $(*)$ is $0$, and hence $u-u_h=0$.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you!